# What is the meaning of "authoritative" and "authoritative" for GCP IAM bindings/members

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-gcp

I am trying to understand the difference between `google_service_account_iam_binding` and `google_service_account_iam_member` in the GCP terraform provider at https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/google/r/google_service_account_iam.html.

I understand that google_service_account_iam_binding is for granting a role to a list of members whereas google_service_account_iam_member is for granting a role to a single member, however I'm not clear on what is meant by "Authoritative" and "Non-Authoritative" in these definitions:

> google_service_account_iam_binding: **Authoritative** for a given role. Updates the IAM policy to grant a role to a list of members. Other roles within the IAM policy for the service account are preserved.

> google_service_account_iam_member: **Non-authoritative**. Updates the IAM policy to grant a role to a new member. Other members for the role for the service account are preserved.

Can anyone elaborate for me please?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[This link](https://fabianlee.org/2021/02/05/terraform-using-non-authoritative-resources-to-avoid-iam-membership-dependency-web/) helps a lot. 
Basically it means: 
 if a role is bound to a set of IAM identities and you want to add more identities, authoritative one will require you to specify all the old identities again plus the new identies you wanna add **otherwise any old identities you didn't specify will be unbinded from the role**.
It is quite close to the idea of force push in git cause it will overwrite any existing stuff. In our case it is identity.

Non-authoritative is the opposite:
You only need to care the identity you are updating

Answer (score 20):

"Authoritative" means to change all related privileges, on the other hand, "non-authoritative" means not to change related privileges, only to change ones you specified.

Otherwise, you can interpret authoritative as the single source of truth, and non-authoritative as a piece of truth.

Comment: I echo the first two questions in Stan’s comment.

Comment: Stan's answer is more precise than mine, so please refer to it.

Answer (score 2):

Authoritative may remove existing configurations and destroy your project, while Non-Authoritative does not.

The consequence of using the Authoritative resource can be severely destructive. You may regret if you used them. Do not use them unless you are 100% confident that you must use Authoritative resources.

- [Usability improvements for *_iam_policy and *_iam_binding resources #8354](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-google/issues/8354)

> I'm sure you know by now there is a decent amount of care required when using the *_iam_policy and *_iam_binding versions of IAM resources. There are a number of "be careful!" and "note" warnings in the resources that outline some of the potential pitfalls, but there are hidden dangers as well. For example, using the **google_project_iam_policy resource may inadvertently remove Google's service agents' (https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/service-agents) IAM roles from the project. Or, the dangers of using google_storage_bucket_iam_policy and google_storage_bucket_iam_binding, which may remove the default IAM roles granted to projectViewers:, projectEditors:, and projectOwners: of the containing project**.
>
> The largest issue I encounter with people running into the above situations is that the initial terraform plan does not show that anything is being removed. While the documentation for google_project_iam_policy notes that it's best to terraform import the resource beforehand, this is in fact applicable to all *_iam_policy and *_iam_binding resources. Unfortunately this is tedious, potentially forgotten, and not something that you can abstract away in a Terraform module.

See [terraform/gcp - In what use cases we have no choice but to use authoritative resources?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70736028/terraform-gcp-in-what-use-cases-we-have-no-choice-but-to-use-authoritative-res) and reported issues.

A simple example. If you run the script, what you think will happen. Do you think you can continue using your GCP project?

```
resource "google_service_account" "last_editor_standing" {
  account_id   = "last_editor_standing"
  display_name = "last editor you will have after running this terraform"
}

resource "google_project_iam_binding" "last_editor_standing" {
  project = "ToBeDemised"
  members = [
    "serviceAccount:${google_service_account.last_editor_standing.email}"
  ]
  role     = "roles/editor"                                    
}
```

This will at least delete the [Google APIs Service Agent](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/service-accounts#google-managed) which is essential to your project.

If you still think it is the type of resource to use, use at own your risk.