# Grant access to specific BQ table via terraform

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, terraform-provider-gcp

I want to grant `READER` access to 3 group emails.

```
variable my_external_users {
  type = map(any)
  default = {
    group_1 = {
      group_by_email = "email_1@group.com"
      role           = "READER"
    }
    group_2 = {
      group_by_email = "email_2@group.com"
      role           = "READER"
    }
    group_3 = {
      group_by_email = "email_3@group.com"
      role           = "READER"
    }
  }
}


resource "google_bigquery_dataset" "my_dataset" {
  dataset_id    = "MY_DATASET"
  location      = var.region
  project       = var.project

  dynamic access {
    for_each = var.my_external_users
    content {
      role           = access.value.role
      group_by_email = access.value.group_by_email
    }
  }
}
```

I believe doing this will grant the entire dataset to the users. I only want to grant access to a specific table called `my_table`. However, I'm not able to achieve it. I'm not sure where to specify `table_id` at.

Answer (score 1):

There are 3 [Terraform resources](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/bigquery_table_iam) allowing you to control the IAM at table-level :

- `google_bigquery_table_iam_policy`
- `google_bigquery_table_iam_binding`
- `google_bigquery_table_iam_member`

Depending on what you want (authoritative IAM, authoritative for a specific role, or non-authoritative), you can use one of those resources.

For example, if you're going for the authoritative one on the `READER` role (`google_bigquery_table_iam_binding`) :

```
resource "google_bigquery_table_iam_binding" "binding" {
  project    = "my-project"
  dataset_id = "MY_DATASET"
  table_id   = "my_table"
  role       = "roles/bigquery.dataViewer" # maps to READER role
  members    = [
    "group:email_1@group.com",
    "group:email_2@group.com",
    "group:email_3@group.com",
  ]
}
```

Comment: Hi, I think this is answer I'm looking for. Can you elaborate what it means authoritive & non-authoritive? I'm torn in between `binding` or `member` to be used

Comment: Authoritative replaces all IAM, while non-authoritative allows to have other IAM permissions, set via console for example. You can take a look this question for more info : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63915353/what-is-the-meaning-of-authoritative-and-authoritative-for-gcp-iam-bindings. If you are sure that ONLY your 3 groups will be data viewer on your table, then you can go for `binding`. Otherwise, if you have other groups or users or service accounts that are data viewer, but not set with Terraform, go for `member`.