# Terraform & GCP : How to specify the same role for several users?

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-gcp

I have been using this piece of code to specify a number of users that can impersonate a service account :

```
resource "google_service_account_iam_binding" "super-admin-impersonators" {
  provider = google.as_super_admin
  for_each = toset([
    for user in var.user_accs_impersonators_info.as_super_admin :
    "${user.acc_type}:${user.acc_details.email}"
  ])

  service_account_id = google_service_account.terraform-super-admin.name
  role               = "roles/iam.serviceAccountTokenCreator"
  members            = [each.key]
}
```

It was working well when I was using only one user in the associated `input & *.tfvars`

In the `input.tf` :

```
variable "user_accs_impersonators_info" {
  type = map(
    list(object({
      acc_type = string
      acc_details = object(
        {
          email = string
        }
  ) })))
}
```

in the `inputs.tfvars`

```
user_accs_impersonators_info = {
  as_super_admin = [
    {
      acc_type = "user",
      acc_details = {
        email = "old_corp_email@domain.com"
      } 
    },    
  ],
}
```

As I was logged on `gcloud` with the `old_corp_email@domain.com`, everything worked swimmingly.

Now I have a new corp email `new_corp_email@domain.com` so I tried to add it to the `inputs.tfvars`

```
user_accs_impersonators_info = {
  as_super_admin = [
    {
      acc_type = "user",
      acc_details = {
        email = "old_corp_email@domain.com"
      } 
    },    
    {
      acc_type = "user",
      acc_details = {
        email = "new_corp_email@domain.com"
      } 
    },
  ],
```

After I performed `terraform apply`, it said what I was expecting : `Plan: 1 to add, 0 to change, 0 to destroy.`. But when I went to the IAM/permissions for this impersonated service account, I found that the `old_corp_email@domain.com` was stripped of the `roles/iam.serviceAccountTokenCreator`, and that it could no longer impersonate the relevant service account.

So I thought, maybe it is because I am using `google_service_account_iam_binding` that is **authoritative** instead of `google_service_account_iam_members` that is **non-authoritative**, but the [documentation](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/google_service_account_iam#google_service_account_iam_member) clearly states :

> google_service_account_iam_binding: Authoritative for a given role. Updates the IAM policy to grant a role to a list of members. **Other roles within the IAM policy for the service account are preserved**.

So it should've preserved the role for the `old_corp_email@domain.com`.

I tried using `google_service_account_iam_member` instead, but it does not support the same arguments and I get this error :

```
│ Error: Unsupported argument
│
│   on impersonators_x_users.tf line 17, in resource "google_service_account_iam_member" "super-admin-impersonators":
│   17:   members            = [each.key]
│
│ An argument named "members" is not expected here. Did you mean "member"?
```

Comment: All else being equal, why not correct the resource usage to per-member instead of all members? That would certainly fix your usage error, but perhaps not achieve the desired objective.

Comment: That introduces so much code duplication though... every time I have a new user I have to copy paste this block no?

Comment: I don't understand why `binding` and `member` ressources work so differently...

Comment: 1. Not unless your actual config code is different than what is in the question 2. You would need to consult the API documentation to answer that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are both answers to the questions :

## Authoritative vs non-authoritative distinction

> So I thought, maybe it is because I am using google_service_account_iam_binding that is authoritative instead of google_service_account_iam_members that is non-authoritative, but the documentation clearly states :
>
> > google_service_account_iam_binding: Authoritative for a given role. Updates the IAM policy to grant a role to a list of members. Other roles within the IAM policy for the service account are preserved.

Indeed, `google_service_account_iam_binding` is **Authoritative**, it preserves **Other** roles for the service account or user account. It does **not preserve the same role for several accounts when changed**. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63915353/what-is-the-meaning-of-authoritative-and-authoritative-for-gcp-iam-bindings) explains it very well :

> if a role is bound to a set of IAM identities and you want to add more identities, authoritative one will require you to specify all the old identities again plus the new identies you wanna add otherwise any old identities you didn't specify will be unbinded from the role.

Perhaps, I was also using `members = [each.key]` erroneously.

## How to specify the same role for several users :

> I tried using google_service_account_iam_member instead, but it does not support the same arguments and I get this error : Error: Unsupported argument

I misunderstood the different mode of operation of `member` in `google_service_account_iam_member` and `members` in `google_service_account_iam_binding`

The answer is to use the following ressource block, by looping through the input variables but without putting it in a list.

```
resource "google_service_account_iam_member" "super-admin-impersonators" {
  provider = google.as_super_admin
  for_each = toset([
    for account in var.user_accs_impersonators_info.as_super_admin :
    "${account.acc_type}:${account.acc_details.email}"
  ])

  service_account_id = google_service_account.terraform-super-admin.name
  role               = "roles/iam.serviceAccountTokenCreator"
  member             = each.value
}
```